# htaccess - Difference between .* and \*

Tags: .htaccess, user-agent

I would like to allow a robot with the user agent ECLoadToEdge/383175. Since I cannot confirm if the 6 numbers will change, I intend to use an asterisk.

May I know the difference between:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ECLoadToEdge\*$
```

and

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ECLoadToEdge.*$
```

Would it be better to use !^ECLoadToEdge.[0-9]{6} instead of * for performance?

Answer (score 0):

This rule is wrong:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ECLoadToEdge\*$
```

SInce it will try to match literal asterisk in user agent.

You should just use:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !^ECLoadToEdge
```

Since you don't care what comes after `ECLoadToEdge`